# DB schema migration tool for CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, database-schema

Is there a good tool for managing changes to MySQL schemas? Either standalone, or integrating with the CodeIgniter framework.
I'm coming at this idea with experience using CakePHP's DB migration tool, so something similar would be great.

Comment: this could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089817/what-are-some-database-migrations-tools-database-change-management-for-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [Doctrine migrations](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/migrations) project among other Doctrine projects.

Comment: @jlb No you don't have to use Symfony. Doctrine integrates nicely with other frameworks and tools. I use it with Zend Framework

Answer (score 0):

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Migration_Add_blog extends CI_Migration {

    public function up()
    {
        $this->dbforge->add_field(array(
            'blog_id' => array(
                'type' => 'INT',
                'constraint' => 5,
                'unsigned' => TRUE,
                'auto_increment' => TRUE
            ),
            'blog_title' => array(
                'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                'constraint' => '100',
            ),
            'blog_description' => array(
                'type' => 'TEXT',
                'null' => TRUE,
            ),
        ));

        $this->dbforge->create_table('blog');
    }

    public function down()
    {
        $this->dbforge->drop_table('blog');
    }
```

Check it from http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/migration.html